# Updating Controls(Progressbar, Label etc.) while some code is running in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm using a third part program COM interface to run my some models. At the same time tCOM-interface gives me an oppurtunity to chec is model still running and what is it's progress/complete percentage with below codes.

But my main problem is winform controls doesn't updating themselves.

```
Private Sub NewMethod()
        Dim obj As IScrBackgroundSolverResult

        'This is COM interface procedure runs my model at the 3rd part program
        ‘Runs some code in background   
        obj = integBG("D:\Test\sample_model.mnf")

        ' Returns True if it's running otherwise False - This information comes from 3rd part's com interface isRunning() function
        obj.isRunning()

        ' Returns True if it's running otherwise False - This information comes from 3rd part's com interface getProgress() function
        ' It's start from 0 to 100
        obj.getProgress()

        While obj.isRunning = True
            ProgressBar1.Value = obj.getProgress
            Label1.Text = "Running"
        End While
    End Sub
```

Functions are working properly but as i said i couldn't update my below code section elements.

```
   While obj.isRunning = True
        ProgressBar1.Value = obj.getProgress
        Label1.Text = "Running"
    End While
```

Comment: What you have there is called a "busy wait" and it is probably the worst construct in all of programming. That loop is going to push your CPU to run at 100% and, as long as the loop is running, the UI thread is not free to actually update the graphical representation of those controls. NEVER use a busy wait. Time to do some research on alternatives.

Comment: So if you put a timer there and put the progressbar inside to get a value from obj.getProgress() does it get a percentage progress number or not?